# ofstream fails to open existing file depending on file size

Tags: c++, windows, ofstream

I have noticed that `std::ofstream` sometimes fails to open existing files. After a little investigating, I found that the issue depends on the size of the file to be opened.

For example, I used the following code to try opening files around the 4 GiB mark:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
constexpr size_t operator ""_MiB(unsigned long long i)
{
    return i * 1024 * 1024;
}
constexpr size_t operator ""_GiB(unsigned long long i)
{
    return i * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (size_t fileSize {4_GiB - 3_MiB}; fileSize < 4_GiB + 12_MiB; fileSize += 1_MiB)
    {
        remove("test.raw");
        std::ofstream os {"test.raw", std::ofstream::binary};
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer {std::make_unique<char[]>(fileSize)};
        os.write(buffer.get(), fileSize);
        os.close();
        std::ofstream os1 {"test.raw", std::ofstream::binary};
        std::cout << fileSize / 1_MiB << " MiB os1.good(): " << os1.good() << std::endl;
        os1.close();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
4093 MiB os1.good(): 1
4094 MiB os1.good(): 1
4095 MiB os1.good(): 1
4096 MiB os1.good(): 0
4097 MiB os1.good(): 0
4098 MiB os1.good(): 0
4099 MiB os1.good(): 0
4100 MiB os1.good(): 0
4101 MiB os1.good(): 0
4102 MiB os1.good(): 0
4103 MiB os1.good(): 0
4104 MiB os1.good(): 1
4105 MiB os1.good(): 1
4106 MiB os1.good(): 1
4107 MiB os1.good(): 1
```

This surprises me as I thought opening an existing file with `ofstream` was supposed to truncate that file, which it does for the successful file sizes. `fstream` shows the same behaviour if the file is opened with `fstream::trunc` or without `fstream::in`. Otherwise opening the failing files with `fstream` or `ifstream` works just fine.

I realize that I can simply delete the file first, like in the example above, and then use `ofstream` to create a new file, but I would much rather understand what causes this behavior and if I can get rid of it.

I'm on Windows 10, compiling with some version of msvc 2015 for C++14.

Is there a sensible reason behind this behavior? What causes it?

Comment: 4 GB is a common file system limit. So I assume it has nothing to do with C++ but only with your operating system i.e. the file system of the volume you try to use the file on.

Comment: Did you step into the `fstream` c'tor? Where is the implementation failing?

Comment: @Superlokkus That was my first thought as well, but then again truncating files that are 4 GiB + 8 MiB works just fine. Similarly, truncating an 8 GiB file works, whereas a 7.5 GiB file doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried it compiled for x64?

Comment: @DDrmmr The deepest I can step into is open, which ist called by the constructor. Inside open, _Fiopen(_Filename, _Mode, _Prot) is called and fails, but that is an intrinsic function that I cannot step into.

Comment: @Superlokkus I am compiling for x64. Probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: Not necessarily, I had wild hunch it could be some 32 integer overflow which might be solved by the different type aliaes on x64. But I am pretty sure its pure a bug of the MSVC implementation, try to test your code on linux or mac with gcc and libstdc++ and and exfat or clang with libc++ and APFS.